# Use ExpressionVisitor to change 'obj == value' to 'obj.Equals(value)'

Tags: linq, expressionvisitor

I'm trying to compare an object with a random value, which could be an ID, and ObjectKey or even with the same object. In short, I want to compare an object with anything, not just the same type.

To do this, I overrode the Equals() and GetHashCode() for the object, and it is working as expected. But I noticed Linq will not call these methods when I search via 'obj == value'.

If I change the queries to 'obj.Equals(value)', the Equals() method is called as it should. But it's not what I need.

Further, I've tried to overload '==' and '!=' operators, but as I'm searching via interfaces, these overloads are not being called.

At the end, I can't just change all my queries by hand, because someone may use the '==' anywhere in the future, breaking the code.

So I come to ExpressionVisitor. I noticed I can rewrite expressions for my Linq queries, but I'm kinda clueless. I've tried some examples I found, but I got some sort of errors.

Finally, this is what I need via ExpressionVisitor:

replace this:
var objects = ctx.Where(obj => obj == value);

to this:
var objects = ctx.Where(obj => obj.Equals(value));

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay. Found it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //the sample:
        Expression<Func<string, bool>> expr = name => name == "AA" || name.Length > 0 || name != "b";
        Console.WriteLine(expr);
        EqualsModifier treeModifier = new EqualsModifier();
        Expression modifiedExpr = treeModifier.Modify((Expression)expr);
        Console.WriteLine(modifiedExpr);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
//the ExpressionVisitor
public class EqualsModifier : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public Expression Modify(Expression expression)
    {
        return Visit(expression);
    }
    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
    {
        if (b.NodeType == ExpressionType.Equal)
        {
            Expression left = this.Visit(b.Left);
            Expression right = this.Visit(b.Right);
            MethodInfo equalsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string) });
            return Expression.Call(left, equalsMethod, right);
        }
        else if (b.NodeType == ExpressionType.NotEqual)
        {
            Expression left = this.Visit(b.Left);
            Expression right = this.Visit(b.Right);
            MethodInfo equalsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string) });
            return Expression.Not(Expression.Call(left, equalsMethod, right));
        }
        return base.VisitBinary(b);
    }
}
```

These all output to:

Original:
name => (((name == "AA") OrElse (name.Length < 0)) OrElse (name != "b"))

Converted:
name => ((name.Equals("AA") OrElse (name.Length < 0)) OrElse Not(name.Equals("b")))

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. You can write a proxy query provider that passes the query to the real provider after rewriting the expression.

You can also pursue the approach that "LinqKit" uses with it's `AsExpandable` rewriter. This approach is much easier but requires inserting these calls into each query.

You also could use Roslyn to perform a one-time refactoring of the source code. The drawback with that is that the source code will look less nice with those `Equals` calls.

I don't have the necessary time to sketch these solutions because they are a lot of work. For `AsExpandable` you can find working code on the web. I'm sure there are tutorials for writing a LINQ provider as well.